# Formatting HTML in Angular project. Force the wrapAttributes in vscode only to angular component tags

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

After searching for a while as I couldn't find a way to achieve what I want posting the question here. I want to format the angular HTML file in a way that is explained below.

There was enough way to format. Using extensions or overwriting the vscode settings by `"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force"`
This is how the file is formatted after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
[image]

I want only the angular component selectors' attributes to be formatted as shown below.
[image]

Any extensions or customizations or any better way to do that is appreciated?

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you find the solution by any chance?

Comment: @Dmytro Not really. Please add an answer if you've found any. Whatever I've found were not actually doing it the way as I want and I didn't consider writing a plug-in for that too.

Comment: Well, I removed Beautify and installed Prettier. It works well now)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following option in VS Code settings:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "preserve-aligned"
```

If you split the angular components' attributes into different lines (and keep the remaining HTML attributes in a single line), it will correctly format you document without breaking the "rules" you defined.

Yes, it has a bit of manual work, but is the best alternative I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution.
Install `Beautify` plugin for vscode and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Beautify is deprecated as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I used `Ctrl + K + S` for the first time and after that it continued saving withoud reformatting

[image]